# How can I get a list from model for the template

Tags: django, templates, view, model

in the models.py, I have a model which has a list attribute:

```
Class Controller(models.Model):
    def controller(self):
        result = []
        #...do some works here...
        result = xxx
```

Now I want to use the "result" attribute in the template, in views.py I have:

```
def results(request):
    cmodel = Controller()
    cmodel.controller()
    firstList = get_list_or_404(Controller, 'I am not sure how to write this filter')
    return render_to_response('blablabla/')
```

I am not sure how to write the filter, since the samples are giving something like "pk=1", but I don't have any primary keys or ids for the 'result' object. Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `controller` function should return `result`:

```
Class Controller(models.Model):
    def controller(self):
        result = []
        #...do some works here...
        result = xxx
        return result # <----------
```

And then you can get it as:

```
c = Controller()
result_list = c.controller()
```

Is that what you want?

Comment: Maybe you want to use `Controller.create()`, that save the model on db. or call `save()`